Hot water flow speed from direct unvented cylinder and cold water speed
I see some direct unvented hot water cylinders are advertised that they can provide a high Litres/min hot water flow.
But I'm wondering does that also mean it would help with cold water to have a higher Litres/min flow?
For example, Heatrae Sadia advertises that "Megaflo Eco Plus delivers outstanding high flow rates of up to 176 litres per minute. This ensures an abundant and powerful supply of hot water at all outlets."
So this means hot water flow will be good. But what about the cold water, would the cold water flow be as good as a result of the good hot water pressure?

try again, you are not making sense

What exactly is your issue?

Just updated the post with some more info

The manufacturer gave me the answer: "Those figures [the advertised flow rates] are the maximum flow rate the cylinder can support. To achieve these values you would need to have that flow rate there in the first place. The Megaflo cylinder doesn’t increase the flow rate of the hot or cold water. What you put into the tank is what you’ll get out of it."

First of all you can not do that with cold water.
When water is heated up it expands, and in closed container (unvented) the pressure rises and you get temporary higher flow.
Temporary because when you drain the unvented cylinder (use hot water) the pressure will drop rapidly to equalize with the inlet temperature.
If you want to raise the cold water pressure you need a booster pump.
